# I have dataset named song_analysis it has 23 columns out of which 3 are character ( performer name , songs name , genre ) l

Tags: r, testing, random-forest, prediction, training-data

My aim is to create models train & test to predict and find lowest RMSE

After which I have to use the train model prediction to test on 2nd dataset named as ( scoringData , which do not have my target variable rating in it )

I have tried multiple algorithms like lm , random forest , ranger , etc

But the main issue is , when I convert performer column from character to factor & then I sort it with top 5 performers , so I get 5 levels & the rest I get is NA values ( don’t know why , and then I put that NA value in others )

I get RMSE n all for train model

But when I predict it on 2nd dataset ( socringData ) it triggers error like
Factor levels are not present in training model

Is there a way I can tackle this , I am completely new in the field of coding
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of some data (e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, c(1, 3, 5)])` for the first 10 rows of columns 1, 3, and 5 - pick just enough rows and columns to illustrate the problem), and also please show the code you are using and the desired output for the corresponding input.

Comment: But generally, you need the same factor levels in your train and test sets. If you set all but the top 5 performers in the train set to `NA`, then you need to keep only those same 5 performers in the test set. If you look at the top 5 performers of the test set, they will be different and your model won't know what to do with them. (Though I don't understand why you want to do that at all... I don't know what your outcome is but including performer as a predictor seems a little sketchy.)

Comment: I want to use rating ~ performer + songs + genre + other numerical variables in my model to get low RMSE score

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.